# Comment dit-on « pick up game » de hockey?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

En anglais, on dirait « *a pick-up game of hockey* » pour un jeu où tout le monde peut venir jouer.

Existe-il quelque chose comme:

> libre match de hockey?

Comment: Dans un contexte sportif, on utilise plutôt les mots *partie* ou *match* que le mot *jeu*. Et on dirait plutôt *match libre* que *libre match*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quelques propositions lues sur [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=pick-up+game) :

> partie amicale
>
> partie improvisée
>
> jouer au hockey avec ses copains

On peut également utiliser *match* à la place de *partie*.

J'ajouterai aussi :

> match ouvert à tout le monde